# Qt eventCallback on C#

Tags: c#, c++, qt, pointers

I have an issue that doesn't allow me to get events from a dll with Qt to a program on C#.
The events comes but i need to force the Window's events queue where they are using Application.doEvents()

For the callback i'm using a pointer which send data to the c# program that be captured by the following method

```
public byte OnKpeDllEvent(int category, IntPtr pInfo)
    {
        KPE_EVENT_INFO Info = new KPE_EVENT_INFO();
        if (pInfo != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            m_hInstance = pInfo;
            object struttura = Marshal.PtrToStructure(pInfo, typeof(KPE_EVENT_INFO));
            if (struttura != null)
                Info = (KPE_EVENT_INFO)struttura;
        } 
}
```

This other method is where i send events from another method i garantee that works

```
void KpeQTLibrary::onConnected() {
KPE_EVENT_INFO einfo{};

einfo.nLine = -1;
einfo.nSize = sizeof(KPE_EVENT_INFO);

if (m_pCallbackProc != NULL)
    m_pCallbackProc(KPE_EVENT::CONNECTED, &einfo);

qDebug() << KPE_EVENT::CONNECTED;
}
```

I hope I was clear enough

Comment: What's the purpose of `Info` variable?

Comment: @hyde the **Info** variable is a struct with two variables inside. You can see in the c++ code what i pass through but is not important for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've resolved my problem because some of the QT Methods needs to be called from the main thread.

`this.Invoke(new Action(() => Initialize()));`

Where Initialize() is the main method where i start all of the functions.